# Prevent script from sudoing

Tags: sudo, root, homebrew

I have a  script that runs an utility every two days. This utility does some stuff on my system. It is a very known, widely used piece of open source software.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#...do stuff here
utility
```

Sometimes, but not always, `utility` will need me to enter my password so it can do its thing. I'm not watching `utility` run, and I'm not looking at any output either, `1>/dev/null`. So I'd like for any attempt `utility` makes to `sudo` to automatically fail. Later I can run it manually and see what it needs superuser access for.

The problem is that it's not my script sudoing, it's `utility`. `utility` updates regularly so I don't want to edit it. Setting SUDO_ASKPASS to something useless looked promising but it requires `sudo` to have been caled with `-A` from `utility`. `utility` man page and online docs also don't have a way to "prevent sudo", neither did I have any luck googling "prevent system wide sudo."

I'm thinking of using this `fake-sudo-test.bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FAKE_SUDO="/usr/local/bin/sudo"
echo "echo 'no sudo for you $0' && exit 1" > $FAKE_SUDO
chmod u+x $FAKE_SUDO
sudo echo "I got superuser access"
\rm $FAKE_SUDO
```

This works because my $PATH has `/usr/local/bin` in front of `/usr/bin`.

Do you know a better way to do it?

PS:  `utility` is `brew`, from the homebrew package manager for macOS, and I'm using `brew upgrade` in question. I thought making the question more generic would make it more useful.

```
$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.17p1
    Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.17p1
    Sudoers file grammar version 45
    Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.17p1
```

Comment: You could create a function named `sudo` that exits if called

Comment: That's true. :)

Comment: @Jesse_b A shell function would not be callable from within the `utility`.

Comment: `brew` practically never calls `sudo` (and if it does it calls `/usr/bin/sudo` so your false sudo won't work), maybe one of the formulae does? Anyway, can't you allow `sudo brew` in `/etc/sudoers` for the user in question? And then run the whole `brew update` with `sudo`?

Comment: Are you sure it’s calling sudo? You could set the sudo prompt to something unique to confirm.

Comment: @nohillside it must be the formulae then.

Comment: @nohillside I'll look into your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: This seems surprising. Can you run it without sending the output to /dev/null for some time to figure out where this is coming from?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm using iTerm2 with the Fira code font. I see a key symbol in the sudo prompt, the same I see when I call `sudo` myself. I'm not 100% sure here, but what else could it be calling?

Comment: @nohillside oh, I may have worded the question badly, I'm calling `brew upgrade` actually. Does that still seem odd to you?

Comment: Yes, it still looks odd. I run `brew update` weekly from an admin account, never had to enter my password so far

Comment: `brew update` will only fetch the latest `brew`. `brew upgrade` upgrades outdated, unpinned formulae. That is, if I understood the man page correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot ask for a password if it is not associated with a terminal:

```
setsid brew < /dev/null &> /dev/null
```

Or, if you want to capture its output:

```
setsid brew < /dev/null |& cat
```

That is, supposing you have [`setsid`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/setsid.1.html), which apparently [may not be available on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590905/is-setsid-command-missing-on-os-x). If you want it and don't have it there are [implementations available](https://github.com/jerrykuch/ersatz-setsid).

If you don't have `sedsid` but you have [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/at.1.html):

```
[ -e ~/brew_$$.log ] && rm ~/brew_$$.log
at now << eof
brew > ~/brew_$$.lo_ 2>& 1 || true
mv ~/brew_$$.lo_ ~/brew_$$.log
eof
while ! [ -e ~/brew_$$.log ]; do sleep 1; done
cat ~/brew_$$.log && rm ~/brew_$$.log
```

will run `brew` now-ish detached from the terminal, capture the output and copy it into the output stream of the script.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: I got `setsid` from `util-linux` (using brew of course :p) and it works. I tried using `at` first, but getting `at` enabled on macOS was a pain. Tried everything here: https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can disable the effect of the setuid bit for the process and all other processes launched from it by enabling the `no_new_privs` flag (see `prctl(2)`). In shell scripts, you can do this with the `setpriv` utility from the `util-linux` package:

```
$ setpriv --no-new-privs sudo -v
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

So modifying your script to run `setpriv --no-new-privs utility` instead of `utility` should do the job, as long as you can live with the noisy error message above.

(Unfortunately, you mention `brew`, and this probably doesn’t work on macOS… but perhaps it still helps someone else.)

Comment: I didn't know about this, thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `setpriv` doesn't seem to have an implementation for macOS. But yeah, nice you added it to the thread anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take yourself out of `/etc/sudoers`. This will make all sudo attempts fail.

   You may need to comment out this line:

   ```
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   ```

   Make sure you have an alternate way of gaining root (e.g. root password) so that you can undo this.
2. Modify this line in `/etc/sudoers`:

   ```
   Defaults        env_reset
   ```

   into

   ```
   Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=-1
   ```

   This makes sudo never ask for a password. ([Source.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636092/how-to-get-sudo-to-prompt-you-for-a-password-each-time))
3. All failed sudo attempts are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`. Run `utility`, and look for a line like this in `auth.log`:

   ```
   Jul  4 12:23:07 host sudo: test_perm : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/nick ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/echo
   ```

   (This might be logged to somewhere else on macOS; I'm not sure.)

Comment: I think on my sudoers setting the timeout to -1 is making the timestamp never expire. I'll test it on linux and I think it'll work as we expect... I edited the post with sudo -V info. I still need to test taking myself out of the sudoers though.